# Problem with reusable MKAnnotationView to show distinct images

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I am showing 3 distinct annotations in a map. To achive this I have a enum as a class variable which indicates the current value of the image name to be set in the MKAnnotationView property. I have subclassed MKAnnotationView to sore a class variable to get the image name in case of annotation reuse.

The problem is that when I drag the map leaving the annotations out of view and when I drag it again to see the annotations, these have their images exchanged.

My enum and custom MKAnnotationView class:

```
    enum AnnotationIcon: String {
        case taxi
        case takingIcon
        case destinyIcon
    }

final class MyMKAnnotationView: MKAnnotationView {
    var iconType: String = ""
}
```

And this is my viewFor annotation function:

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        
        guard !(annotation is MKUserLocation) else {
            return nil
        }
        
        let identifier = "Custom annotation"
        
        var annotationView: MyMKAnnotationView?
        
        guard let dequeuedAnnotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier) as? MyMKAnnotationView else {
            let av = MyMKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
            annotationView = av
            annotationView?.annotation = annotation
            annotationView?.canShowCallout = true
            annotationView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            annotationView?.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 35).isActive = true
            annotationView?.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 35).isActive = true
            annotationView?.iconType = annotationIcon.rawValue //AnnotationIcon enum class variable
            annotationView?.image = UIImage(named: annotationView?.iconType ?? "")
            
            return av
        }
        annotationView = dequeuedAnnotationView
        annotationView?.image = UIImage(named: annotationView?.iconType ?? "")
        
        return annotationView
    }
```

Images that explain the problem:

Before the draggin:

[image]

After the draggin:

[image]

What is the way for each annotation to retrieve the correct image in case of reuse?

Thank you.

Comment: Checking the memmory address of the MKAnnotationViews, they are being relocated over the map. Not exchanging their images.

Answer (score 1):

Before reusing the `MyMKAnnotationView` you've to empty the already set `image` in the `prepareForReuse` method.

```
final class MyMKAnnotationView: MKAnnotationView {
    var iconType: String = ""
    //...
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        image = nil // or set a default placeholder image instead
    }
}
```

Update: As suspected the `iconType` is not getting set before you're trying to set the `image` of `MyMKAnnotationView`. Either you need to set the `iconType` before setting the `image`, like this:

```
annotationView?.iconType = AnnotationIcon.taxi.rawValue
annotationView?.image = UIImage(named: annotationView?.iconType ?? "")
```

You can improve this a lot by being the image returning logic to the `AnnotationIcon`.

```
enum AnnotationIcon: String {
    //...
    var annotationImage: UIImage? { UIImage(named: rawValue) }
}
```

Then change the `MyMKAnnotationView` as follows:

```
final class MyMKAnnotationView: MKAnnotationView {
    var iconType = AnnotationIcon.taxi {
        didSet {
            image = iconType.annotationImage // image is set whenever `iconType` is set
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

Then in `viewForAnnotation`:

```
var iconTypes = [AnnotationIcon]() // should be equal to the number of annotation

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    //...
    dequeuedAnnotationView.annotation = annotation
    dequeuedAnnotationView.iconType = iconType
}
```

Comment: Hello @Frankenstein, I have tested your solution but the MKAnnotationView images continue to be exchanged between them. Could the entire MKAnnotation being relocated?

Comment: Did you check the correctness of your logic? Where exactly are you setting `iconType` that you're passing to get the image as parameter?

Comment: I set that value when the user tap some button: for example, if the user tap a button to indicate is location at determinated time, the Enum variabe is set to .takingIcon. I have updated the post with images that describe the issue.

Comment: @AndoniDaSilva As suspected it was because you were trying to set the image before `iconType` value was set. Check the update. Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you only set the `iconType` property when you create the annotation view. When an annotation view is reused, you set the image based on that property rather the current annotation.

Really, there is no need for the `iconType` property. You should just always use an `icon` value from your annotation. The annotation is the data model.

You also don't set the view's `annotation` property correctly in the case of reuse.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        
        guard let myAnnotation = annotation as? MyAnnotation else {
            return nil
        }
        
        let identifier = "Custom annotation"
           
        var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier) as? MyMKAnnotationView
        if annotationView == nil {
            annotationView = MyMKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
            annotationView?.canShowCallout = true
            annotationView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            annotationView?.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 35).isActive = true
            annotationView?.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 35).isActive = true
        }
        annotationView?.annotation = MyAnnotation
        annotationView?.image = UIImage(named: MyAnnotation.icon.rawValue)
        
        return annotationView
    }
```

Comment: Paul, the problem is that at the time of reuse, if I directly use the value stored in the class variable "annotationIcon", this value may not correspond to the type of annotation. For example, when I put an annotation of type destination, this is the value that is stored in the class variable "annotationIcon", therefore, at the time of reuse, all annotations would show the image for the value "destination" . That is why I wanted to assign to each MKAnnotation the image that they have to show using a subclass.

Comment: You shouldn't use a class property. The icon type should be a property of your annotation. Views shouldn't store state; they are lightweight and reusable. Your data model stores state (in this case your annotation is your. Odel)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue subclassing the MKPointAnnotation to know what type of Annotation I am reusing:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        
        guard !(annotation is MKUserLocation) else {
            return nil
        }
        var annotationView: MKAnnotationView?
        switch annotation {
        case is MyCustomTaxiAnnotation:
            annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: annotationTaxiID, for: annotation)
        case is MyCustomOriginAnnotation:
            annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: annotationOriginID, for: annotation)
        case is MyCustomDestinyAnnotation:
            annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: annotationDestinyID, for: annotation)
        default:
            annotationView = nil
        }
        if annotationView == nil {
            switch annotationIcon {
            case .destinyIcon:
                annotationView = MyDestinyView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: annotationDestinyID)
                annotationView?.annotation = MyCustomDestinyAnnotation()
            case .takingIcon:
                annotationView = MyOriginView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: annotationOriginID)
                annotationView?.annotation = MyCustomOriginAnnotation()
            case .taxi:
                annotationView = MyTaxiView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: annotationTaxiID)
                annotationView?.annotation = MyCustomTaxiAnnotation()
            }
        } else {
            annotationView?.annotation = annotation
        }
        return annotationView
    }
```

For example, the Taxi annotation is a subclass of MKPointAnnotation:

```
let annotation = MyCustomTaxiAnnotation()
final class MyCustomTaxiAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation {
///...
}
```

So, taking in account that, I am able to reuse a custom annotation view properly. I have also register the custom MKAnnotationView:

```
map.register(MyOriginView.self, forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: annotationOriginID)
        map.register(MyDestinyView.self, forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: annotationDestinyID)
        map.register(MyTaxiView.self, forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: annotationTaxiID)
```